# java problems with variable ":"

Tags: java, variables

i have a problem with some java code.

here the code :

```
label820: result.value = -2;
if(a=10){b=a; break label820:}
```

the second line generate this error (`Syntax error on token ":",; expected`), when i put ; at the end of line he stay with same error.

Comment: you should use semicolon instead of colon

Comment: Breaks are only allowed in loops and switch statements. Labeled breaks only in loops.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Just because it's possibly a syntax error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to

```
label820: {
    result.value = -2;
    if(a==10) { // I assume you wanted to compare a to 10 and not assign 10
        b=a;
        break label820;
    }
}
```